# Remove duplicate data selected form database with array unique

Tags: php, arrays, duplicate-data

Below is my code i want to remove duplicate value selected from the database using array_unique() not DISTINCT in mysql query please i need help with this Thanks

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM place";    
$result2 = mysql_query ($query2) or die('query error');
while( $line2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){   
$e = $line2['event_title'];

$array = array($e);
$result = array_unique($array);
echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM place";    
$result2 = mysql_query ($query2) or die('query error');
$events = array();
while( $line2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){   
  $events[] = $line2['event_title'];
}
$events = array_unique($events);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($events);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: It work but how can i remove this ([1] =>) because i want to put it in a link like this <a href=''>$events</a> an echo it thank you